# iOS10 swift 2.2 share on Instagram openURL& canOpenURL change

Tags: swift, ios9, instagram, ios10, url-scheme

Im working with the function of sharing photos to Instagram with swift 2.2 and it works on iOS9 but failed with iOS10, is there any difference between iOS9 and iOS10 ?
Here is how I achieve it on iOS9, thanks for any advices.

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

var yourImage: UIImage?
var documentController: UIDocumentInteractionController!

func shareToInstagram() {

 let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://app")

        if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL!)) {

            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage!, 100)

            let captionString = "caption"

       let writePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("instagram.igo")
       if imageData?.writeToFile(writePath, atomically: true) == false {

                return

            } else {
 let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: writePath)

                self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: fileURL)

                self.documentController.delegate = self

                self.documentController.UTI = "com.instagram.exlusivegram"

                self.documentController.annotation = NSDictionary(object: captionString, forKey: "InstagramCaption")
                      self.documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)

            }

        } else {
            print(" Instagram isn't installed ")
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is it failing? Do you get an error? Does it fail silently?

Comment: Hi @NicolasMiari, it just no response when I try to share photo to instagram on iOS 10 device. Yes it fail silently, app still working after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved , just update to xcode8 and using swift2.3.